# upserting an object in MongoDB using PyMongo

Tags: mongodb, bulkupdate, pymongo-3.x

I intend to upsert a specific field into existing mongo object like below -

```
from pymongo import UpdateOne

# data_dict has less than 1000 items
for content_id, content_rank in data_dict.items():
                operations.append(UpdateOne(
                {"content_id": content_id},
                { "$set": { "ranks": content_rank } }, 
                upsert=True))
result = collection.bulk_write(operations)
```

I want to upsert `ranks` dictionary object into each of the content objects. The code above is running without any errors but I am unable to see changes reflected in the database. I would like to point out that `ranks` fields is not present in any mongo objects when this script is being run.

Note: MongoDB v3.2.10 is being used

Comment: `{"content_id": content_id}` might have not matched any documents, can you check `result` it will have the no of documents matched, updated, upserted?

Comment: You were right. I expected the pymongo wrapper to throw some kind of error but it seems to fail silently.